# Create text tattoo in Gimp

Tags: gimp

Is there a way to append a tattoo on somebody's arm in *Gimp*? The tattoo will not be an image but writing from a *text tool* with some nice font (or another fast way). So, I need to create a fitting effect from this writing. I already found how to do a tattoo from images but it would be slow for me to create an image from every writing. I need to do many fitting writings like in [memento](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_%28film%29) movie.

Comment: @xralf sorry, that is not the way we roll here, just cause we skipped a few you cannot use that argument to keep a question open. Ask Ubuntu is not the place for Gimp tutorials. I have close this for now since it does not fit the Q&A format.

Comment: @BrunoPereira OK, I asked here because I'm not from Windows world (I know that gimp is multiplatform). On superuser I could asked but they don't accept my questions, though I have [not](http://superuser.com/users/71797/xralf?tab=questions) [bad reputation](http://superuser.com/users/71797/xralf?tab=answers)

Comment: @xralf take to [meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/), create a question with "My question was closed" and explain you made it and ask why it was closed. You will get an answer there and depending on that we can further see what we do with this question. For now I will keep it closed and any further comments will be ignored and purged. Let us not discuss this here please.